# Failing to send multiple files with curl to send-anywhere.com

Tags: curl, multipartform-data, crystal-lang

I was trying to build a CLI tool in Crystal to use `send-anywhere.com` from the command line.

Sending multipart is not builtin in Crystal but before writing my own I thought I would try to use cURL to see how exactly I should make it but I can't even get it to work with cURL!

The issue is that when sending **more than one file** with cURL their server only sees 1 file incoming, they do see the total length but fail at 50% since they were only expecting one file.

What kills me is that it works in the browser, I have the network inspector open and I fail to see the difference with my cURL request.
I've tried setting the Expect header to 100-continue, I've compared them but I fail to see what could make it work with the browser and not curl.

Here's the command I tried with cURL all with the same result, the server ends up seeing only 1 file incoming not 2.

For testing purposes I was using a few copies of a generic LICENSE file.

```
curl -F file1=@LICENSE -F file2=@LICENSE1 https://...their.weblink...
```

I've seen in the inspector that Chrome names the file name="file[]" in Content-Disposition, so I tried it myself (same result):

```
curl -F file[]=@LICENSE -F file[]=@LICENSE1 https://...their.weblink...
```

I also tried these 2 commands using `-H "Expect: 100-continue"` with same result.

At this point I got mad and thought I'd try it myself, maybe cURL can't do it properly (highly unlikely imo, much higher chance that I'm doing something wrong).

So before writing it from scratch I tried an implementation that was used by a Telegram bot see here: https://github.com/hangyas/TelegramBot/blob/b3fcbbb621bd669bbafe9f3e91364702d06d1e10/src/TelegramBot/http_client_multipart.cr

It's pretty straightforward but I still get the same issue. Only the first file is recognized.

Note: everything works fine with both cURL and the Crystal implementation when sending only one file.

I'm going crazy, what's the difference between the browser which works and the other two? What am I not seeing?

I'm not looking for an implementation but just for someone to point out what I missed that would make multiple files recognized correctly?

Comment: Note mutlipart should come into the standard library fairly soon, see https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/2967

Comment: @JonneHaß Yeah I know I've been following that issue for a while! But I'm not even sure it will fix this issue I'm having.

Comment: I don't get this site, it just does nothing for me when I add a file (assuming I tried the right site and you just forgot a dash in the domain).

Comment: @JonneHaß Yeah I ran into the same issue just open the inspector and you'll see in the console many ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, disable adblock/ghostery to fix this. Or simply run it through an incognito window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is for educational purposes only, actually doing this violates
>   the terms of service. It has a documented API you should use
>   instead, after given an API key.

It's important to announce the number of files to the `key` endpoint correctly. So the whole flow looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First we need to get a device key by registering ourselves as a
# device. For that we need a profile name. We need to store the
# received cookie and send it with the subsequent request.
profilename="$(openssl rand -hex 6)"
curl -c .session -vL https://send-anywhere.com/web/device \
  -d "os_type=web" \
  -d "profile_name=$profilename" \
  -d "manufacturer=Linux" \
  -d "model_number=Firefox" \
  -d "app_version=48" \
  -d "device_language=en-US"

# We need to know the individual filesizes in bytes as well as
# the total size we're going to upload
file0name="foo.txt"
file0size="$(wc -c "$file0name" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
file1name="bar.txt"
file1size="$(wc -c "$file1name" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"
filesize="$(echo "$file0size + $file1size" | bc)"

# Using that info and the cookie we got from the device key
# we can correctly announce our upload
key="$(curl -b .session -vL https://send-anywhere.com/web/key \
  -d "file[0][name]=$file0name" -d "file[0][size]=$file0size" \
  -d "file[1][name]=$file1name" -d "file[1][size]=$file1size" \
  -d "file_number=2" -d "file_size=$filesize")"

# We get some JSON back with the URL to send to the receiver
# and the URL to upload back
url="$(echo "$key" | ruby -rjson -e 'print JSON.parse($stdin.read)["link"]')"
upload_url="$(echo "$key" | ruby -rjson -e 'print JSON.parse($stdin.read)["weblink"]')"

echo
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Receive 2 files of $filesize bytes at $url"
echo "------------------------------------------------------------"
echo

# And finally do the upload
curl -vL "$upload_url" \
  -F "file[]=@$file0name" \
  -F "file[]=@$file1name"
```

Comment: AH! I never thought to look at the previous request since they were working fine (and yes I have my own API key). Also I didn't understand completely but is it against their ToS to send multiple files using the API (with a valid key)? Or simply to send files without using an API key?
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Also maybe they just forgot to add this to their API doc: https://send-anywhere.com/web/page/api#web-gui There's no mention of having to specify the files count!

Comment: Also maybe it wasn't clear but I was using my own API key since the beginning. But the key is not needed for the last step (uploading to the weblink) That's why there was no mention of it. It's only needed to perform the register_device and get_6_digits_key steps.

Comment: I wrote this because I used the endpoints for the web application, not the API.

Comment: Ah ok well it works the same it's just undocumented in their API page. Thanks!